# How do i find the distance between a point and 2 equations, if Y is not known?

Tags: geometry

If e: 2x+y+1=0; f: x+2y-3=0, determine p such that the distances from A(1,p) to the
lines e and f are equal.
I`m kinda lost, I know this is probably a 10th grade problem but I really need help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the distance formula from a point to a straight line? And how to solve 3 equations with 3 variables?

Comment: |Ax+Bx+C|/Sqrt(A**2 + B**2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P = (1, y)$, we want to determine $y$ such that the distances from $P$ to the line $2x + y + 1 = 0$ and the line $ x + 2 y - 3 = 0 $ are equal.

Set up the distances equation:

$ \dfrac{ | 2(1) + y + 1 | }{\sqrt{5}} = \dfrac{ | 1 + 2 y - 3 | }{\sqrt{5}}$

So we have to solve:

$ | 3 + y | = | 2 y - 2 | $

Squaring,

$ (3 + y)^2 = (2 y - 2)^2 $

$ y^2 + 6 y + 9 = 4 y^2 - 8 y + 4 $

$ 3 y^2 - 14 y - 5 = 0 $

$ (3 y  +  1)(y  -  5) = 0$

Hence the two solutions for $y$ are $ y = -\dfrac{1}{3} $ and $ y = 5$

Comment: Thats it thanks brother.

Comment: may i ask just one question though? Why did u square it?

Comment: @CDXX Because of the absolute value.

Comment: i looked it up u were of great help thank you